# Эффекты на div при создании через js

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Есть вопрос. Как мне сделать эффект на div сразу после создания. Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку создавался div через createElement, добавлялся через AppendChild, и если у всех блоков фон белый, то только что созданный блок за секунду менял свой цвет от серого к белому. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Приложите код, в котором Вы пытались решить эту проблему и что у Вас не получилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот решение за счет css keyframe-animation

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  let el = document.createElement('div');
  el.classList.add('element');
  document.body.appendChild(el);

}
```

```css
.element{
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: expand 1s;
}

@keyframes expand {
  from {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>add</button>
```